# In Google+ Share button how set custom image , title and description by JavaScript.?

Tags: javascript, google-plus, sharing

I am using a Google+ share feature in my page. There are many article in list(on single page ) so my question is that how will i set Google + share image ,title and description for respected article so at the time of sharing it show relative image and content in Google share page By JavaScript.

Thanks ...